# Bug: Stack Overflow not clickable anymore when saving comment edit with enter

Tags: bug, status-completed, internet-explorer

Occurs on IE11 EDGE mode win8.1 (My pc). User [Ismael Miguel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2729937/ismael-miguel) notified me that this problem also happens on versions IE9 to 11 from Vista to 8.1, but not on IE8.

Still occurs on IE Edge WIN 10 PRO. Time to take a look at it.

**The problem:**

When you `edit` your comment and save it using <kbd>enter</kbd> it keeps a focus on the `textarea` preventing you to click on links or other page elements until the element defocuses by clicking multiple times randomly on the page. Attempting to select text seems to work the fastest.

*Note: Posting a new comment and submit it using <kbd>enter</kbd> doesn't show the described behavior. Then the defocus works properly.*

**To reproduce:**

- Add a comment
- Open edit mode on comment
- Save changes using <kbd>enter</kbd> (return)
- Cursor keeps blinking after comment and clicks on the page are not working

This behavior stops once the focus is from the hidden input element. To defocus you need to click multiple times somewhere on the page.

**Desired behavior:**

Onblur should occur immediately and should not prevent the user from clicking page elements.

*This problem should occur on all instances of StackExchange.*

Comment: are we suggesting this is a stackoverflow bug? or an IE11 behavior bug?

Comment: Tested quickly on Firefox 39. Doesn't shows this behavior. However a fresh post on IE works fine, editing doesn't somehow. Did an edit on this post, also present on Meta and maybe all stack sites.

Comment: IE sucks. Don't use it.

Comment: @bjb568 I tend to disagree. IE11 is actually a fast reliable and well behaving browser. I've seen enough issues in all browsers to say that each browser has its own quirks and bugs. Lot's of people use Internet Explorer and are happy with it. Don't offend them.

Comment: It was a LQ browserling, now it's a troll. Eg https://status.modern.ie/mixblendmode and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: Doesn't support CSS resize, zoom-in and zoom-out cursor values, tabsize, appearance…

Comment: @bjb568 - regardless. It would be irresponsible to ignore the 8% on IE11 (http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php), and ~10-25% on IE(all) http://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-january-2014-yearly-review/

Comment: @SW4 I'm not saying it shouldn't be supported, I'm saying it shouldn't need to be supported. So stop using it!

Comment: @bjb568 Why so negative. Microsoft brought some good ideas to the browser in the past. They devised dragdrop behavior. Introduced innertext and they had filters, deprecated but they did modern CSS3 styling avant la lettre. In the past I cursed enough because my page got rendered incorrectly on IE or FF (Ye olde time before Chrome). Nowadays when using `doctype` I hardly run into lay-out problems.

Comment: Drag and drop is awkward and doesn't work on mobile. innerText is wrong - use the actual DOM (which BTW isn't made out of text, rather nodes). No, CSS is a standard that they didn't do, and that they still aren't up to pace with today.

Comment: Greetings. I've posted about this same issue by mistake. I wasn't aware that your question already existed. After a brief discussion in the comments, I've decided to drop here some additional informations. 1st - This issue happens on all versions from IE9 and up, it works perfectly on IE8 (go figure out!?). 2nd- As a consequence, this issue isn't caused only on Windows 8.1, but also goes down to Windows Vista SP1. 3rd - This issue also locks the mouse scroll in such a way that the page is unusable until you click randomly.

Comment: (... continuing ...) If you want, you can check my question here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283337/after-editing-a-comment-the-prompt-stuck-on-textarea-after-pressing-enter , which also also have a printscreen that you can use to illustrate the problem. (You can blur out the text, it doesn't matter).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks for your thorough research. Quick replying is surely a nuisance with this bug. Hopefully the coders can find I workaround. This bug should be present in the whole of stack exchange.

Comment: @Mouser If by "This bug should be present in the whole of stack exchange." you mean that the bug should happen everywhere, I can confirm that it happens every where across all the StackExchange network. The printscreen I've provided comes from another website other than sackoverflow. If you mean that this should be shown everywhere across all the meta websites, I agree with you since this here isn't getting any attention from the developers. A 'bad' workaround would be to emulate a click on the `Save Edit` button when the "enter" key is pressed.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel since every stackExchange is build on the same model or template I have no reason to believe why this problem shouldn't arise on superuser.stackexchange.com or dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Mouser It happens on ux.stackoverflow.com, which is from where I took the printscreen. And it only happens when you edit. When you add a comment, everything is fine.

Comment: @Mouser Here is the link to the comment itself: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/71779/which-share-icon-is-most-appropriate-for-web/71783#comment110767_71791

Comment: @Mouser As a side note, you forgot to mention that it works as intended on IE8. To confirm this, one can use IETester (it's free, but you pay for extra debug tools). Notice that it may crash all the time. Complatibility mode for IE8 works quite well too.

Comment: @Mouser Possibly using some ugly hack like conditional compilation to check IE's version is enough to supress this bug by forcing it to emulate a click on the submit button and forcing to focus on something else.

Comment: Just to update: THE DAMN BUG IS STILL HERE!!! No one fixed it!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The devs must have found another bug that needed urgent fixing...

Comment: @rene Yes, because blocking the whole freaking page **for over a year** isn't urgent at all. No, it isn't. They must be thinking: "The page doesn't work after editing a comment. Let's make an awful-looking login box!"

Comment: You were able to leave another comment so it isn't that blocking and login works ;) .... but this question can use some attention from SE maybe in the spirit of [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)...

Comment: @rene leaving new comments isn't the issue, editing them produces the bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed on build 3762 for MSE/MSO, and build 2883 for other sites. Tested on Edge; I presume the same fix will work on IE too.

Comment: Nope, the bug still happens. Tested on 11.0.9600.17416.

Comment: Notice the prompt at the side: http://i.imgur.com/54e5kvp.png

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Build 3762 isn't deployed yet. That's how we do things at Stack Overflow, we mark tickets `status-completed` when the code is checked in. You look at the footer of the page to see what the current build is. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-completed/info for more info.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel See also: [a recent request for chat build numbers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267550/13), precisely so people know when chat features/fixes have been released. :-)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Build 3762 (MSO/MSE only) is deployed. Build 2883 will land in the next 5 minutes.

Comment: Yup, it's working!!! It's a shame that it took almost a year to solve this... Can you please edit your answer so I can upvote?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Here we go. :-)

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how long I waited for this bugfix. Oh wait, you do.. But it is a welcome fix.