# After editing a comment, the prompt "stuck" on <textarea> after pressing "enter"/"return" on IE11

Tags: bug, internet-explorer

I don't know if this is the right place or not, but I will post this here.

I'm using IE11 (yeah..... yeah..... I know) while I play my games.

Sometimes, I have periods where I'm not paying attention to the game.

And then, I see an interesting question and I post a comment.

But sometimes, I screw it and misspell something.

I'm used to press "enter"/"return" on Opera 12.17 to save my edits.

On IE11, it gets stuck!

The focus won't go away even after saving and some random clicks.

Here is an example showing the prompt:

[image: Printscreen of a comment I posted on ux.stackoverflow.com]

I don't know if this is the right place to post it, but this happens across **ALL** the StackExchange network, and here is where it annoys me the most.

It's so annoying that I can't even scroll the page!!!

My UA String:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Translation: Windows 8.1 Pro 64bits running IE11 32bits (default) with most of settings on default, except the Hardware Acceleration and Autocorrect where disabled.

---

My guess here:

Probably there is an issue in removing the focus on the `<textarea>` after saving it.

Adding `$(window).focus();` (didn't checked if you use jQuery and didn't checked your javascript code.... yet!) *might* solve it.

---

**Edit:**

This is not a Windows 8.1 specific bug, as it also happens on Windows 7.

UA String:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Again: Windows 7 Home Edition x64 SP1 running IE11 32 bits with all the default settings.

Comment: You're not alone in noticing this, and this is indeed the right place to post this. (Here or on MSE, that is.)

Comment: @Kendra It is indeed a duplicate, but the information there is near null. All it says is that the blur doesn't work on IE11 on Windows 8.1. Also, notice that I'm also referring to the fact that the page won't scroll or react in any way.

Comment: @Kendra As a side note, I just tested on IE11 using Windows 7 and the problem is the same. I added it to the post.

Comment: @Kendra About it being marked as "This question may already have an answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281290/bug-onblur-not-working-correctly-on-editing-comment-when-using-enter ", it isn't true since there are no answers there. At the most, it could be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: The "may have an answer here" part is just the stock message for when someone flags as a dupe- On meta, a question does not have to have an answer for it to be the target of a duplication. As it stands, the issue of comments being broken on IE11 has already been raised, and as you noted, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Kendra No disagreement in there. I'm not discussing and I'm not disagreeing, but the other answer provides minimal to no information. And the case is *kinda* different now, since it isn't *just* for Windows 8.1. The only information there is "`Occurs on IE11 EDGE mode win8.1`" and how to reproduce it (which I failed somehow to do). That thread has no solutions and all that there is is a discussion of how much IE sucks.

Comment: @Kendra Actualy, this is a new bug introduced in IE9. It works great on IE8.

Comment: Ismael, the proper way to handle the other question not having enough information is to comment on it with the extra information so the OP can update that question. It doesn't matter what is in the comments there now, if you comment the OP will be notified and can take action on your comments. Talking to me about how much information your question has over the other question is really not doing anything but cluttering up the comment thread here. Side note: If anyone had commented that the issue was appearing on different systems in the other question, it would have that info.

Comment: @Kendra Alright, I will take sure the information is passed.

Comment: On a side note. Used to work for a software company. My post provides the information needed for everybody to reproduce this problem. More information is simply not needed. The test cases you provided are surely helping.