# How do you bring a bug post back into attention

Tags: bug, questions

On December the 29th 2014 I've posted a bug on Stack Exchange websites occuring in Internet Explorer:

[Bug: Stack Overflow not clickable anymore when saving comment edit with enter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281290/bug-onblur-not-working-correctly-on-editing-comment-when-using-enter)

This bug is on every Windows edition and on every version since IE8. The new Microsoft Edge didn't solve the problem (in fact it became worse). However there hasn't been a reaction to it and the bug is still here after a half year.

What can you do to raise attention for this problem. As a frequent user of Stack Overflow I find it a really annoying bug for which the solution isn't: change to Firefox or Chrome.